# neo4j cypher APOC.case returns null properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Can anyone explain why this apoc procedure returns null properties on the yielded value?? In this example the predicate is false.

```
MATCH (p:Posts) 
 CALL apoc.when(
  p.region_audience IS NOT NULL AND NOT (2 IN p.region_audience),
  "RETURN null",
  "RETURN p AS post",
  {p:p})
YIELD value
RETURN value,p.title;
```

So while `value` which should be equal to `p` is returned completely if you try to `return value.title` you get null. If your return `p.title` you do get the title. I know it has something to do with how the `yield` is computed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: please give us sample data to work on. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to your condition `p.region_audience IS NOT NULL AND NOT (2 IN p.region_audience),` in `apoc.when` query:

In the **ifQuery**, the `apoc.when` returns `RETURN null` (**value** will be **null**) and in **elseQuery** returns `p` with Alias `post`.

So to access the result of the `apoc.when` query, you've to use the alias given in **ifQuery** or **elseQuery** : `value.post.title`.

> **Note that the result of `value` will always be `null` if the `ifQuery` is executed *(when the condition is respected)*.**

Comment: I did indicate that the path I am examining is when the predicate is false..i.e. RETURN p AS post. I did test value.post.title even though it gave the correct result...I got a warning message 'Provided Property Key is not in Database' ...:post. If this is the correct solution then I shouldn't have a warning...since it may not work in production

Comment: This is the **apoc.when** signature: `apoc.when(condition, ifQuery, elseQuery, params )`, all about the condition is true or false no other else. According to your query, in **ifQuery** you `RETURN null` which will make the yielded value to **_null_**.

Comment: The result will only be null if the predicate is true.. which is what I want.... When the predicate is true it works fine. the problem is when the predicate is false ... this is the path I am investigating... the yielded vaule doesn't seem to be consistent... well the value is correct but there's a ⚠️ warning message as I stated above.